# Having issues with XSL templates applying template to a node set that is returned by a specified key

Tags: xml, templates, xslt

I am creating an XSL style sheet that I need to transform into a new XML document using the separate XML document.

It is telling me to create a key (which I did), insert a for-each element using the Muenchian grouping once again. Each time it goes through the loop, it asks me to write this code/the "Customers" as the root element: `

```
             <Customer CustomerID="CustomerID">
               <Summary>
                <TotalOrders><xsl:value-of select="count(key('CustomerList', CustomerID))" /></TotalOrders>
                <TotalCharges><xsl:value-of select="format-number(key('CustomerList', OrderCharge, '$#,##0')" /></TotalCharges>
               </Summary>

               <Orders>
                 <xsl:apply-templates select="Order(key('CustomerID', CustomerList))" />
               </Orders>
             </Customer>
             </xsl:for-each>
```

But the parts that kind of confuse me is that the "count" in "TotalOrders" is the count of orders within the "CustomerList" key,  for the **current** CustomerID. It keeps saying current, but I am not exactly certain what that means or if I am looking too much into it. Also, it says "charges" should be the sum of "OrderCharge" and I am not certain if I need to add `sum` or not.

Also, the "Order element" is supposed to be a new template that should match the "Order" template and describes all orders made by the customer. And lastly, here is the part that is most confusing to me:

```
        <Orders>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="Order(key('CustomerID', CustomerList))" />
            </Orders>
```

This is supposed to APPLY the "Orders" template for the node set returned by the "CustomerList" key, but I am not sure how I can do both without it being invalid.

Here is the full XSL for reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

     <xsl:output method="html"
      doctype-system="about:legacy-compat"
      encoding="UTF-8"
      indent="yes" />     

    <xsl:key name="CustomerList" match="Order" use="CustomerID" />

      <xsl:template match="/">

        <xsl:element name="Customers">
          <xsl:for-each select="//CustomerID[generate-id()=generate-id(key('CustomerList', CustomerID)[1])]">
                 <xsl:sort select="CustomerID" />

                 <Customer CustomerID="CustomerID">
                   <Summary>
                    <TotalOrders><xsl:value-of select="count(key('CustomerList', CustomerID))" /></TotalOrders>
                    <TotalCharges><xsl:value-of select="format-number(key('CustomerList', OrderCharge, '$#,##0')" /></TotalCharges>
                   </Summary>

                   <Orders>
                     <xsl:apply-templates select="Order(key('CustomerID', CustomerList))" />
                   </Orders>
                 </Customer>
                 </xsl:for-each>
       </xsl:element>
     </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Order">
      <Order OrderID="OrderID" OrderDate="OrderDate" ShippedDate="ShippedDate">
        <SalesRep><xsl:value-of select="SalesRepID" /></SalesRep>
        <Charge><xsl:value-of select="format-number(OrderCharge, '$#,##0')" /></Charge>
      </Order>
    </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is a chunk of the XML for reference:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="youngston.xsl" ?>

<Orders>
    <Order OrderID="order53102">
        <OrderDate>2/6/2017</OrderDate>
        <CustomerID>cust640-79</CustomerID>
        <SalesRepID>rep25</SalesRepID>
        <ShippedDate>2/8/2017</ShippedDate>
        <OrderCharge>39.74</OrderCharge>
    </Order>
    <Order OrderID="order53103">
        <OrderDate>2/6/2017</OrderDate>
        <CustomerID>cust514-13</CustomerID>
        <SalesRepID>rep24</SalesRepID>
        <ShippedDate>2/8/2017</ShippedDate>
        <OrderCharge>30.47</OrderCharge>
    </Order>
    <Order OrderID="order53104">
        <OrderDate>2/8/2017</OrderDate>
        <CustomerID>cust473-29</CustomerID>
        <SalesRepID>rep17</SalesRepID>
        <ShippedDate>2/13/2017</ShippedDate>
        <OrderCharge>138.2</OrderCharge>
    </Order>
    <Order OrderID="order53105">
        <OrderDate>2/8/2017</OrderDate>
        <CustomerID>cust316-14</CustomerID>
        <SalesRepID>rep17</SalesRepID>
        <ShippedDate>2/10/2017</ShippedDate>
        <OrderCharge>147.39</OrderCharge>
    </Order>
    <Order OrderID="order53106">
        <OrderDate>2/9/2017</OrderDate>
        <CustomerID>cust211-28</CustomerID>
        <SalesRepID>rep32</SalesRepID>
        <ShippedDate>2/13/2017</ShippedDate>
        <OrderCharge>111.77</OrderCharge>
    </Order>
    <Order OrderID="order53107">
        <OrderDate>2/9/2017</OrderDate>
        <CustomerID>cust473-29</CustomerID>
        <SalesRepID>rep15</SalesRepID>
        <ShippedDate>2/14/2017</ShippedDate>
        <OrderCharge>82.8</OrderCharge>
    </Order>
```

It validates, but when I view the result doc by opening a browser, it appears as unreadable repeats of "rep" and "order" with ID numbers...I would truly appreciate any help! Thank you.

Comment: "*it asks me to write this code*", "*It keeps saying current,*", etc.  What is "it"?.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: The textbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some serious syntax issues, such as:

```
 <xsl:value-of select="format-number(key('CustomerList', OrderCharge, '$#,##0')" />
```

(unbalanced parentheses) and:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="Order(key('CustomerID', CustomerList))" />
```

(`Order` is not a function).

Next, you are not using Muenchian grouping correctly. If you want to group orders by customer, you must define your key as:

```
<xsl:key name="order-by-cust" match="Order" use="CustomerID" />
```

and use (only) `CustomerID` when using the key.

You also need to learn about *attribute value template*. This:

```
<Customer CustomerID="CustomerID">
```

needs be:

```
<Customer CustomerID="{CustomerID}">
```

otherwise the literal string "CustomerID" will be returned as the value of the attribute.

Finally, if you want to view this in a browser, you probably want to output this as HTML. You did set your output method to HTML, but you are in fact outputting XML elements (as opposed to an HTML table, for example).

For your reference, here's your attempt, corrected:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="order-by-cust" match="Order" use="CustomerID" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <Customers>
        <xsl:for-each select="Orders/Order[generate-id()=generate-id(key('order-by-cust', CustomerID)[1])]">
            <xsl:sort select="CustomerID" />
            <Customer CustomerID="{CustomerID}">
                <Summary>
                    <TotalOrders>
                        <xsl:value-of select="count(key('order-by-cust', CustomerID))" />
                    </TotalOrders>
                    <TotalCharges>
                        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(key('order-by-cust', CustomerID)/OrderCharge), '$#,##0')" />
                    </TotalCharges>
                </Summary>
                <Orders>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('order-by-cust', CustomerID)" />
                </Orders>
            </Customer>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Customers>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Order">
    <Order OrderID="{@OrderID}" OrderDate="{OrderDate}" ShippedDate="{ShippedDate}">
        <SalesRep>
            <xsl:value-of select="SalesRepID" />
        </SalesRep>
        <Charge>
            <xsl:value-of select="format-number(OrderCharge, '$#,##0')" />
        </Charge>
      </Order>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Test input**

```
<Orders>
    <Order OrderID="order53102">
        <OrderDate>2/6/2017</OrderDate>
        <CustomerID>AAA</CustomerID>
        <SalesRepID>rep25</SalesRepID>
        <ShippedDate>2/8/2017</ShippedDate>
        <OrderCharge>39.74</OrderCharge>
    </Order>
    <Order OrderID="order53103">
        <OrderDate>2/6/2017</OrderDate>
        <CustomerID>BBB</CustomerID>
        <SalesRepID>rep24</SalesRepID>
        <ShippedDate>2/8/2017</ShippedDate>
        <OrderCharge>30.47</OrderCharge>
    </Order>
    <Order OrderID="order53104">
        <OrderDate>2/8/2017</OrderDate>
        <CustomerID>CCC</CustomerID>
        <SalesRepID>rep17</SalesRepID>
        <ShippedDate>2/13/2017</ShippedDate>
        <OrderCharge>138.2</OrderCharge>
    </Order>
    <Order OrderID="order53105">
        <OrderDate>2/8/2017</OrderDate>
        <CustomerID>AAA</CustomerID>
        <SalesRepID>rep17</SalesRepID>
        <ShippedDate>2/10/2017</ShippedDate>
        <OrderCharge>147.39</OrderCharge>
    </Order>
    <Order OrderID="order53106">
        <OrderDate>2/9/2017</OrderDate>
        <CustomerID>BBB</CustomerID>
        <SalesRepID>rep32</SalesRepID>
        <ShippedDate>2/13/2017</ShippedDate>
        <OrderCharge>111.77</OrderCharge>
    </Order>
    <Order OrderID="order53107">
        <OrderDate>2/9/2017</OrderDate>
        <CustomerID>AAA</CustomerID>
        <SalesRepID>rep15</SalesRepID>
        <ShippedDate>2/14/2017</ShippedDate>
        <OrderCharge>82.8</OrderCharge>
    </Order>
</Orders>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Customers>
   <Customer CustomerID="AAA">
      <Summary>
         <TotalOrders>3</TotalOrders>
         <TotalCharges>$270</TotalCharges>
      </Summary>
      <Orders>
         <Order OrderID="order53102" OrderDate="2/6/2017" ShippedDate="2/8/2017">
            <SalesRep>rep25</SalesRep>
            <Charge>$40</Charge>
         </Order>
         <Order OrderID="order53105" OrderDate="2/8/2017" ShippedDate="2/10/2017">
            <SalesRep>rep17</SalesRep>
            <Charge>$147</Charge>
         </Order>
         <Order OrderID="order53107" OrderDate="2/9/2017" ShippedDate="2/14/2017">
            <SalesRep>rep15</SalesRep>
            <Charge>$83</Charge>
         </Order>
      </Orders>
   </Customer>
   <Customer CustomerID="BBB">
      <Summary>
         <TotalOrders>2</TotalOrders>
         <TotalCharges>$142</TotalCharges>
      </Summary>
      <Orders>
         <Order OrderID="order53103" OrderDate="2/6/2017" ShippedDate="2/8/2017">
            <SalesRep>rep24</SalesRep>
            <Charge>$30</Charge>
         </Order>
         <Order OrderID="order53106" OrderDate="2/9/2017" ShippedDate="2/13/2017">
            <SalesRep>rep32</SalesRep>
            <Charge>$112</Charge>
         </Order>
      </Orders>
   </Customer>
   <Customer CustomerID="CCC">
      <Summary>
         <TotalOrders>1</TotalOrders>
         <TotalCharges>$138</TotalCharges>
      </Summary>
      <Orders>
         <Order OrderID="order53104" OrderDate="2/8/2017" ShippedDate="2/13/2017">
            <SalesRep>rep17</SalesRep>
            <Charge>$138</Charge>
         </Order>
      </Orders>
   </Customer>
</Customers>
```

Comment: Thank you, I learned A LOT thanks to you, and hopefully others will as well. Thanks again.